# Spring 4 Websockets java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, jetty, spring-websocket

I'm new to spring websocket and following this tutorial.[enter link description here](https://gerrydevstory.com/2014/03/04/stock-ticker-demo-webapp-using-spring-4-websocket/). 
 But I'm getting always this exception when running on jetty.

Exeception.

```
2014-11-20 17:56:51.978::WARN:  Nested in org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=http://localhost:8081/springexample/ws/586/krdp8vij/xhr; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure for request http://localhost:8081/springexample/ws/586/krdp8vij/xhr; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/server/ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/server/ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl
    at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest.getAsyncRequestControl(ServletServerHttpRequest.java:202)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.initRequest(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.handleInitialRequest(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal(AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:254)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:311)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.config.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:25)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

My dependencies.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>    
              <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Also my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
              <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
         </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any help? Thanks.

**EDIT**

After changing my pom. This is what I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncSupported()Z
at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl.<init>(ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl.java:59)
at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest.getAsyncRequestControl(ServletServerHttpRequest.java:202)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.initRequest(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.handleInitialRequest(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:156)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal(AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:58)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:254)
... 30 more
```

Comment: Which version of spring are you using?

Comment: @Mithun I'm using version 4.0.2

Comment: We get `NoClassDefFoundError` when **The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.**

This means your dependency configurations are fine. Could you please check if the `spring-web.jar` is available in the lib folder of your deployment package(war)?

Answer (score 1):

The class can be found in spring-web.jar, since version 4.0.0, see [API docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl.html).

**Update:**

> "NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncSupported"

This is a method is available since Servlet 3.x, please check your web.xml header, weather you are using the right version. Check [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.1.2.v20140210/what-jetty-version.html) too, to see if you are using the right Jetty. Must be 8.x or above.

Comment: Thanks for a response, this is what I thought also, but after looking in my jar spring-web is already present.